# Migration internal storage to a new smart contract

Tags: migration

What is currently the best way to migrate data from one contract for example the mapping to a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1) Write some sort of backend program to read data from old contract and save it into the new contract. Pros: easy to implement (if you know some programming language to talk with the blockchain). Cons: Requires other (outside blockchain) technologies and knowledge.

2) Write all the logic in a new smart contract. The contract retrieves data from the old contract and saves it in the new contract. This can either be a middle-man contract (which is used only for the transition) or the actual new contract. Pros: all logic stays in blockchain, no need to write code outside. Cons: Probably a bit costlier in terms of gas compared to option 1. Also easier to make security mistakes.